# Scatter plot code outputting too many series Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm VERY new to VBA. I'm trying to write a code that will output 33 series. The x-values for the first series are in column A and the y-values for the first series are in column C. Then D and F. Then G and I....and so on. (So basically the x-values and y-values are every third column starting from A and C respectively). The values are in rows 2 to 25.

Also the name for each series is in the first row, every third column starting with 2.

The first 33 data points come out OK, but it continues on to produce a bunch on unintended data points. Is there a problem with my loop? Like I said I'm pretty new so it could be something super obvious. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
Sub Scatter

Dim i As Int

Dim name As String


    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

For i = 1 To 33

    name = Cells(1, 3 * i - 1)

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).name = name

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ActiveSheet.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = .range(.Cells(2, 3 * i - 2), .Cells(25, 3 * i - 2))
    ActiveSheet.SeriesCollection(i).Values = .range(.Cells(2, 3 * i), .Cells(25, 3 * i))

    End With


Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Scatter()

Dim i As Integer
Dim cht As Chart, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set cht = sht.Shapes.AddChart().Chart
    cht.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

    For i = 1 To 33
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
            .Name = sht.Cells(1, (3 * i) - 1)
            .XValues = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, (3 * i) - 2), sht.Cells(25, (3 * i) - 2))
            .Values = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 3 * i), sht.Cells(25, 3 * i))
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```